# Access a variable inside a context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I want to access with the `eval` function a variable outside the definition of a context manager.

I have:

context.py

```py
class Context:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print(eval(self.arg1))
```

main.py

```py
from context import Context

a = 'outside context'

with Context(arg1='a') as c:
    pass
```

The script `main.py` should have accessed to the variable `a`, but i have the following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/code/context-test/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    pass
  File "c:\code\context-test\context.py", line 9, in __exit__
    print(eval(self.arg1))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Is that even possible to access the variable `a` just by passing its name to a function or class in an other module?

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT** as a precision in the end I want to do something like that, and on exit perform operations on `a` in the context manager.

```py
from context import Context

with Context(arg1='a') as c:
    a = 1
    a *= 2
```

Comment: Context manager or not doesn't really matter, that variable simply isn't in scope, and neither should it be. Why not pass `a` instead of `'a'` into `Context`?!

Comment: Yes I should have precised that in the end I even want to create a variable in the context manager and on exit perform actions on it, but hold the reference before

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should only ever pass *values* around, not *names of variables*. Even if there is some way to bend over backwards and resolve the variable from its name from a different scope, it would likely be very unexpected behaviour, so… better not to in the first place.

Comment: What you intend to do is not possible in a general case: you can only create global (not local) variables dynamically. And that will most likely end up in a convoluted logic, worse maintainability, and lack of support from IDEs and linters.